# How to run django + email handler in App Engine

Tags: python, django, email, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I try to run django and email handler app together in Google App Engine.  I use code as google's doc and it must be run with python27. When I converted to code for python37 got `script must be set to "auto"` error. Can anyone help me? My code as below. Thanks in advance

**app.yaml:**

```
runtime: python37

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT myproject.wsgi

env_variables:
...

inbound_services:
- mail
- mail_bounce

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /_ah/mail/.+
  script: handle_incoming_email.app
  login: admin
```

**handle_incoming_email.py:**

```
import logging

from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import InboundMailHandler


class IncomingMailHandler(View, InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, mail_message):
        logging.info("Received a message from: " + mail_message.sender)
```

when I run this error raises from 'script: handle_incoming_email.app' script must be set 'auto'. How can I get handle_incoming_email.py to app.yaml if I set `script: auto`.

## change '.+' as '.*' have tried.

Answer (score 0):

In App Engine Standard, when using the Python3.7 runtime, the `script` tag under the handlers must be set to `auto`. You can check the documentation on this [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#handlers_element) on how the `app.yaml` must be configured, note that it's different than in the Python2.7 runtime, where you had to specify the `script` to run.

You can solve this by modifying your `app.yaml` file, like so:

```
runtime: python37

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT handle_incoming_email.app

env_variables:
...

inbound_services:
- mail
- mail_bounce

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /_ah/mail/
  script: auto
  login: admin
```

Notice how the required change was to set the `script` under `/_ah/mail/` to `auto`, instead of specifying the path to the script to run. The handler then should automatically find the script to execute, from the files you deployed in App Engine.

Next, in your `handle_incoming_email.py` file you are not defining any entrypoint to handle your url `/_ah/mail`, you can solve this by adding the following, for example:

```
import webapp2

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/_ah/mail/', IncomingMailHandler),
], debug=True)
```

Notice now, how I changed the `entrypoint` in your `app.yaml` file to match the newly created WSGI entrypoint in your `handle_incoming_email.py` file.

Also I'm not sure about the **'/.+'** regex for the handler, you should leave it at **'/.*'**.

Comment: Thank you @Joan. If entrypoint is changed, django's wsgi socket will be removed and django cannot run. Is it possible to use together in one entrypoint?

Comment: You are right, the entrypoint should be imported by doing `from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application` and defining `application = get_wsgi_application()`. However, I don't know how your application is configured, and the easiest solution to me would be to build your application on top of [this samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard_python37/django), where you can see how a django application is configured in App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

The handler parameter is used to route requests to static files, then the remaining routes are all routed to your main app (the auto value is the only option for the script element, as mentioned in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#handlers_element)) at your entrypoint. That app must handle requests routing. You can't define another app in the same service.

I'd suggest to deploy your email app as a separate service in your App Engine app. This will allow you to specify specific resources or scaling for each one. This will follow the micro-services architecture principles enforced in App Engine.

Comment: Thank you for your response @LundinCast. At this point, I just used separated apps way. But in this way GAE generates a new subdomain automatically. I cannot use same domain.